# Pasar parametros a una clase auxiliar en android y evitar que los datos se reseteen al matar la actividad

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Tengo un problema...
Quiero pasar varios ByteArray mediante un intent, pero me lanza el siguiente error

```
E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 2827408)
I/System.out: Failure from system
```

Estuve leyendo un poco tratando de arreglarlo con una clase externa al Activity como funcion auxiliar a traves de metodos get y set, trabaja todo bien y dejo de lanzarme el error anterior de JavaBinder, guarda los ByteArray sin problema, pero al momento de realizar el intent del ActivityA al ActivityB, quito de la pila de activities el ActivityA y al momento de querer extraer los ByteArray de la clase auxiliar desde el ActivityB, la misma clase auxiliar me manda datos nulos y al querer almacenarlo en una variable dentro del AvtivityB arroja el siguiente error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Espero haberme explicado bien y me puedan apoyar!!! Gracias!!

Comment: Quisiera saber como evitar que los datos que mandé a la clase auxiliar se borren al momento de cerrar el ActivityA

Comment: Hay varias maneras de hacer esto: puedes hacer persistir los datos en shared preferences, en un archivo local, en Firebase, en una base de datos o pasarlos en el `Intent` si de la actividad en la que estás se pasa a otra. El método que escojas dependerá también de la estructura y cantidad de datos que son. Si se trata de muchos datos por ejemplo tendrías que pensar en base de datos o en Firebase.

Comment: gracias!! lo tendré en cuenta

Comment: El problema parece de persistencia de objetos. Si defines los objetos como variables de la clase de la ActivityA, obviamente dejarán de existir cuando el objeto de la ActivityA se destruya. Así que cuando pasas de una Activity a otra, le tienes que enviar los datos que vas a necesitar en ActivityB. En el onCreate de ActivityB, extraes del Intent los datos y los copias a variables de tu ActivityB, que podrán usarse sin que te de excepción. Si quieres que persistan entre ejecuciones de tu aplicación, entonces lo que te ha dicho @A.Cedano: preferences, bases de datos, etc...

Comment: @SuperG280 gracias, pero justamente eso es lo que inicialmente hacia, pasar todos mis datos al activityB a traves del intent y lo que obtengo es el Failed Binder Transaction!!

Answer (score 0):

Un archivo parcelable sólo puede tener un 1MB de tamaño, por lo que si quieres pasar datos entre activities, una solución recurrente es usar un Repositorio singleton.

Si estás trabajando con Kotlin puedes emplear object y si usas Java pues el patrón de diseño Singleton.  Si estás usando un inyector de dependencias o un service locator, también puedes emplearlo para que el repositorio sea singleton.

Entre activities puedes compartir una lista de id y que la activity secundaria los recupere del repositorio creado.